# Counter in ListView

Tags: android, listview

I want to make a custom Calendar. I've created a layout(linearLayout) that consist of 7 buttons. Now, I'm doing a ListView BaseAdapter in which I want to set texts for those buttons. Text will be the Date, like 5th Jan but only number. The thing is that I don't know how to pass the Date between my views in getView() method.

I've tried to use a global variable but since getView() method is called many times that int variable showed faulty results. Instead of showing 5 or 14 it showed 17 or 29. How to workaround this situation?

What I want:
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 // remember this 7

8 9 10 11 12 13 14 // count from that 7

```
int c; // Global varibale

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.oneweek, null);
    Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button4);
    Button button1 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button12);
    Button button2 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button13);
    Button button3 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button16);
    Button button4 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button17);
    Button button5 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button18);
    Button button6 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button19);
    Button[] buttons = new Button[]{button, button1, button2, button3, button4, button5, button6};

        for(int i = 0; i<7; i++){
                buttons[i].setText("" + c);
                c++;
        }
    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are implementing your own calendar view. You should use an existent library (in my opinion)

Anyway, this code below should answer you question

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    //I suppose the layout is an viewgroup
    ViewGroup view = (ViewGroup) LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.oneweek, null);
    Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button4);
    Button button1 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button12);
    Button button2 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button13);
    Button button3 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button16);
    Button button4 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button17);
    Button button5 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button18);
    Button button6 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button19);
    Button[] buttons = new Button[]{button, button1, button2, button3, button4, button5, button6};

    for(int i = 0; i<7; i++){
        buttons[i].setText((i+1) + (7 * position));
        //You have to add the buttons to the parent
        view.addView(buttons[i])
    }

    return view;
}
```

If you decide to follow this way. You should implement a ViewHolder pattern also